# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - the rest is working fine

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I'm developing a website like instagram in laravel
everything was going fine until i implemented the foreach command

this is my code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 p-5">
            <img src="/images/simbolomax.jpg" class="rounded-circle">
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 pt-5">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline">
                <h1 class="p-2">{{ $user->username }}</h1>
                <a href="/p/create">Aiciona nova receita</a>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="pe-5"><strong>153</strong> receitas</div>
                <div class="pe-5"><strong>23k</strong> seguidores</div>
                <div class="pe-5"><strong>212</strong> seguindo</div>
            </div>
            <div class="pt-4">{{ $user->profile->description }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-5">
        @foreach($user->posts as $post)
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="/storage/{{$post->image}}" class="w-100" style="height:100%">
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

and the error is: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\projetos\easymeal\resources\views\profiles\index.blade.php)`

I can't figure out, send help!

Comment: use

@dd($user->posts) 
just before this line

@foreach($user->posts as $post)
and you will see if there are any problem.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a user with no posts... There goes ERROR. So.... Check user for posts before @foreach.
@if(count($user->posts)>0).... @foreach

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@if ($user->posts->isNotEmpty())
    @foreach ($user->posts as $item)
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="/storage/{{$post->image}}" class="w-100" style="height:100%">
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```